# Winding number of a contour about zero

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $F:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be an analytic function that never takes the value $0$. Let $r>0$ and $\gamma : [0, 2\pi] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be the closed contour defined by $$\gamma (t) = F(re^{it}).$$

Show that $n(\gamma, 0) = 0$, where $n(\gamma, 0)$ is the winding number of $\gamma$ around $0$.

So far I've tried showing that $$|n(\gamma, 0)| = |{\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma}{\frac{dz}{z}}}|,$$

$$\leq |\frac{r}{2\pi i}|*|\gamma|\text{sup}\{|1/z|: z\in\gamma\},$$
$$=\text{sup}\{|1/z|: z\in\gamma\}.$$

But now i'm at a loss, any hints or help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I don't think that's gonna lead anywhere too nice, since the $\sup 1/z$ is not finite

Comment: I think you missed an $r$ in the inequality

Comment: Write it as $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\lvert w\rvert = r} \frac{F'(w)}{F(w)}\,dw.$$